# Query Access through SQL in Excel VBA with Excel variables in WHERE part of query

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I want to be able to look up the minimum/first date in a set of data, then run a query in Access that will delete all the data in a certain table from that day onwards.

What I have so far is:

```
Sub upload()
 Last = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
 Dim LastOrderDate As Date
 Dim LastOrderDateYear As Integer
 Dim LastOrderDateMonth As Integer
 Dim LastOrderDateDay As Integer

 FirstOrderDate = Range("D2")
 FirstOrderDateYear = Year(FirstOrderDate)
 FirstOrderDateMonth = Month(FirstOrderDate)
 FirstOrderDateDay = Day(FirstOrderDate)

 'Import Data to Benji's Ecommerce Database
 ssheet = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
 Set acApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
     acApp.OpenCurrentDatabase ("X:\ECommerce Database.accdb")
     acApp.Visible = True
     acApp.UserControl = True
     acApp.DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM [OrdersDetailed] WHERE Day([OrderDate])=""&FirstOrderDateDay&"" And Month([OrderDate])=""&FirstOrderDateMonth&"" And Year([OrderDate])=""&FirstOrderDateYear&"""
    acApp.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet 0, 9, "OrdersDetailed", ssheet, True, "B1:V" & Last
    acApp.CloseCurrentDatabase
    acApp.Quit
Set acApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

But it doesn't delete anything, it runs properly, but the message box comes up in Access saying that 0 records are being deleted.

Is this possible to do?

Do I need to use different syntax to input the variables?

Thanks

Benji

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your runSQL string to:

```
acApp.DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM [OrdersDetailed] WHERE Day([OrderDate])='" & FirstOrderDateDay & "' And Month([OrderDate])='" & FirstOrderDateMonth & "' And Year([OrderDate])='" & FirstOrderDateYear & "'"
```

Comment: Tried this, but it comes up with: "Compile error: Expected: end of statement"

Comment: I did have to edit it. Did you try the current edit?

Comment: Yep, I did. It doesn't like single quotation marks within the main quotation marks. I tried double as well and doesn't work.

Comment: Check the SQL itself then. I'll edit my answer to cause the script to output to the Immediate window. Copy paste this into a query in the database itself to find the issue with your script.

Comment: Wow, ok so now it is working! But I swear the query looks no different... What did you change in the edits?

Comment: The ampersands were too close to the other text so were causing issues. I'll put my answer back in so you can mark if you wish.

Comment: Ahhh, ok, so I actually needed a space between the " and the & and the variable? I thought vba would create that for me if it was the right syntax. Thanks for your help!